# How to interpret scatterplot to test linearity b/w covariate and DV?

Tags: linear-model, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, ancova, linearity

I'm doing an ANCOVA on a fictitious dataset of math test results (DV) by group (n1 = 50 online training; n2 = 50 no training) with previous math ability as a (covariate) to see if there is a difference between students who did an online training or not on their test performance.

I already tested the following previous assumptions: homogeneity of variances, balanced design (equal samples of 50), and ANOVA to see if there is a difference b/w groups and test scores (w/out accounting for covariate) and there is.

I'm testing linearity b/w covariate and dependent with the following scatterplot:

[image]

I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct, but I see that they do interact, and that not all observations fall within the linear model. Does this mean the assumption is violated?

I tested for homogeneity of regression slopes, and found no statistically significant interaction between groups and covariate:

[image]

How do I continue with my analysis? How can I be sure if there is linearity or not?

Comment: Hi Yael G. Welcome to CV. I have removed the additional part from the title to make it more condensed. The body of the question is already adequately articulating that.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the scatterplot, I don't see any severe departures from linearity. The case would be different if it looked something like the data below, which has obvious issues of nonlinear data:

[image]

I'd say with all other assumptions checked, there is no major issue with your output here so long as there isn't anything else bizarre going on with your test data. [This is a video](https://youtu.be/jwvjDoviJr4) which shows how to check assumptions in SPSS ANCOVAs btw.

Comment: As I'm learning more about data analysis I have now realized my mistake in assuming it wasn't following linearity, I can see this now. Thank you!